# Webgrid - Column header not clickable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have a webgrid with a date column. The date should appear as a link, plus the column should be sortable too.

If I add the date column like below, the column header "Order Date" is coming up as plain text.

```
grid.Column(
      header: "Order Date",
      format: (item) => new HtmlString(Html.ActionLink((string)item.orderdate...)
)
```

If I add the date column without the actionlink, the column header "Order Date" comes up as a link, and I am able to click to sort it.

```
grid.Column("orderdate", header: "Order Date")
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I have the column header clickable/sortable and have the date field as a link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **columnName** attribute.

```
     columnName: "orderdate";
```

here is a simple syntax

```
   grid.Column(
  header: "Order Date",
  columnName: "orderDate",
  format: (item) => new HtmlString(Html.ActionLink((string)item.orderdate...)
  )
```

and most importantly your columnName should be the **EXACT** name of the column present in the database

Comment: I am glad I could help, I myself was stuck with this a few days bak :P

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your grid

```
 var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, canSort: true);
```

It will enable sorting

Comment: I have canSort as true. All the other columns are sortable. It's just this one column, and only when I have the action link. Looks like when the data is inside an anchor tag, webgrid doesn't allow sorting on that column.

Comment: Could it be that you are wrapping Html.ActionLink in an HtmlString. ActionLink already returns MvcHtmlString, so you shouldn't have to create a new HtmlString